# Tracking changes, updates and TODO's in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I usually keep a text file in every project with these fields:

```
- TODO -  
// List of things I need to do (bugs, problems etc.)  

- SOLVED -  
// List of things I've solved  

- CHANGED FILES -  
// List of files I've changed and need to commit
```

Is there a built in feature or a plug-in I can install that does something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For todo and solved you can go to

> View -> Task List

and see the task list window which will show all places in code that you have marked with `//TODO:`
You can also add your own tasks in here and mark them complete.

If you also look at

> Tools -> Options -> Environment/Task List

then you can change which comments appear in the task list.

For a list of changed files it depends on your source control tool of choice - TFS has the pending changes window built-in, AnkhSVN has something similar if you are using subversion.  Not sure about others (I prefer command line with git).